# Python Gtin 8 Code not totaling

Tags: python, string

Hi I have been experimenting for some time to try and total 7 variables at once. I am trying to calculate the 8th number for GTIN 8 codes. I have tried many things and so far I am using float. I Don't know what it does but people say use it. I need to times the 1,3,5,7 number by 3 and 2,4,6 number by 1. Then find the total of all of them added together. I have looked everywhere and I cant find anything. Anything will help. Thanks Ben

```
code = input ("enter 7 digit code? ")
sum1 = 3 * (code[0] + ',')
sum2 = code[1] + ','
sum3 = 3 * (code[2] + ',')
sum4 = code[3] + ','
sum5 = 3 * (code[4] + ',')
sum6 = code[5] + ','
sum7 = 3 * (code[6] + ',')

checksum_value = sum1 + sum2 + sum3+ sum4 + sum5+ sum6 + sum7
b = str(checksum_value)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick solution:

```
x = "1234567"
checksum_value = sum(int(v) * 3 if i in (0,2,4,6) else int(v) for (i, v) in enumerate(x[:7]))

# (1*3) + 2 + (3*3) + 4 + (5*3) + 6 + (7*3)
# ==
# 3 + 2 + 9 + 4 + 15 + 6 + 21
# ==
# sum(int(v) * 3 if i in (0,2,4,6) else int(v) for (i, v) in enumerate(x[:7]))
```

## Explanation:

```
# Sum the contained items
sum(

    # multiply by three if the index is 0,2,4 or 6
    int(v) * 3 if i in (0,2,4,6) else int(v)

    # grab our index `i` and value `v` from `enumerate()`
    for (i, v) in

    # Provide a list of (index, value) from the iterable
    enumerate(
        # use the first 7 elements
        x[:7]
    )
)
```

Comment: Note to others coming to this thread later -- Jon's solution provides the checksum total. You need to go one step further to get the actual check digit.

Comment: Jon's solution is also specific to GTIN-8, which was the OP's request. If you need a solution for other cases such as GTIN-12, -13 or -14, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

GS1 codes come in different lengths, ranging from GTIN-8 (8 digits) to SSCC (2 digit application ID + 18 digits). Here's a simple, general Python formula that works for any length GS1 identifier:

```
cd = lambda x: -sum(int(v) * [3,1][i%2] for i, v in enumerate(str(x)[::-1])) % 10
```

## Explanation:

1. Convert input to string, so input can be numeric or string - just a convenience factor.
2. Reverse the string - simple way to align the 3x/1x pattern with variable-length input.
3. The weighting factor is selected based on odd and even input character position by calculating i mod 2. The last character in the input string (i=0 after the string has been reversed) gets 3x.
4. Calculate the negative weighted sum mod 10. Equivalent to the `(10 - (sum mod 10)) mod 10` approach you'd get if you follow the GS1 manual calculation outline exactly, but that's ugly.

## Test Cases

```
## GTIN-8
>>> cd(1234567)
0
>>> cd(9505000)
3

## GTIN-12
>>> cd(71941050001)
6
>>> cd('05042833241')
2

## GTIN-13
>>> cd(900223631103)
6
>>> cd(501234567890)
0

## GTIN-14
>>> cd(1038447886180)
4
>>> cd(1001234512345)
7

## SSCC (20 digits incl. application identifier)
>>> cd('0000718908562723189')
6
>>> cd('0037612345000001009')
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`enter code here`code = input ("enter 7 digit code? ")
sum1 = 3 * (code[0] + ',')
sum2 = code[1] + ','
sum3 = 3 * (code[2] + ',')
sum4 = code[3] + ','
sum5 = 3 * (code[4] + ',')
sum6 = code[5] + ','
sum7 = 3 * (code[6] + ',')

checksum_value = sum1 + sum2 + sum3+ sum4 + sum5+ sum6 + sum7
b = str(checksum_value)
print(b)
```

Comment: that is how I did it